# List of entities used in intent is incorrect

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In LUIS, on the intent page, I have 5 utterances that use the same entity in each. Under the utterances is the list of entities used in the intent.  As you can see from the attached image, it lists the entity I have used and the correct count (5), but it also lists another entity that I have not used and says there are 2.

I have refreshed the page and trained and it is still showing the incorrect number of entities.  I am concerned this error will affect the results. Is it a known issue, and can it be fixed?

[image: screenshot of LUIS intent page]

Comment: You claim that Entity "Procedure" is present only in other Intents? And that you have only the displayed 5 utternaces in your observed Intent definition?

Comment: Is it possible that some utterances were changed or moved or removed when previously they contained that entity in that utterance?

Comment: Yes, some utterances were removed.  Does the list not update when refreshed?  Normally with only five utterances this would not be a problem but I have some intents with many more utterances spanning pages and it is not possible to see them all at once.

Comment: First commenter - yes, it is as you describe

Comment: are you able to make an export of your LUIS application then import it as another LUIS application and still reproduce described behavior? If so could you share reduced version of export of your LUIS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to export and reimport the app into a new app did not solve the problem, but when I looked at the export file I figured it out.  Actually both of the entities were there in some of the utterances, just hidden one on top of the other, so they didn't show up in the interface.

example utterance:

```
{
      "text": "how much will i be charged for my clonazepam",
      "intent": "PHARMACY_DRUG_INQUIRY",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Prescription",
          "startPos": 34,
          "endPos": 43
        },
        {
          "entity": "Procedure",
          "startPos": 34,
          "endPos": 43
        }
```

Comment: Then you may accept your answer as the correct answer of your question, right?

Comment: Thanks.  First time doing that.

Answer (score 0):

looks more like a portal glitch to me. Have you tried following
1) Logging out of the portal and logging in again to check?
2) If yes, please try to export and reimport the app definition in a new app.
Let us know your observations